# ag grid row lines disappear after i scroll right

Tags: vuejs3, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

[image]

After I scroll right the line color and also border disappear.
That's with vue3 composition API.
It looks like it doesn't render when i scroll.

```
 const columnDefs = ref([
    { field: "Action", cellRenderer: ActionButtons, pinned: 'left', maxWidth: 100},
    { field: 'Case ID' , pinned: 'left'},
    { field: 'Case Title' , pinned: 'left'},
    { field: 'Date and Time' },
    { field: 'History' },
    .
    .
  ]);
```

```
  const rowData = ref([
    {
      'Date and Time': '29/06/2020 11:36:24',
      History: 'Placeholder',
      Username: 'test',
      'Placeholder': 'test',
      'Case ID': 'test',
      'Case Title': 'test',
    },
    .
    .
```